# Side offet linear drain

Tags: shower, drain

I am currently renovating my bathroom and converting my bathtub into a walk-in tiled shower. In the process of deconstruction I've noticed that I cannot center align my drain with the valves and shower head due to the positioning of the floor joists and additional plumbing that is routed through the sub floor, that I don't want to/can't cut. One solution I have found is that I could use a 12 in side offset linear drain that would make the drain appear (mostly) center aligned. [12 in side offset drain](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08ZSPYVPX)

However, that is the only side offset drain I've found in my searching that's 12 inches. The next lowest is around 19 inches, which would lead me back to my first problem of the drain appearing offset. Additionally, that drain appears to have a different outlet that what I notice at any store or even the one I planned on using.

Is there an alternative solution to this problem?
Is it possible to use that offset drain or does anyone have recommendations for one they have used before?

Thanks!

Comment: "that drain appears to have a different outlet that what I notice at any store or even the one I planned on using"; what is it about the outlet that has you concerned?

Comment: If you want some suggestions, [edit] in some clear, focused pics including an overall shot or two, and some detail shots, indicating exactly where the problem is and your envisioned solution. Even with that, it's possible that this will be closed because product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Simple solution - get past the "everything must be lined up" mindset. The drain needs to drain water from the shower - there is no functional benefit from it being "lined up with the shower valves" - just make sure the base is sloped correctly to drain to it, wherever it is. Heck, I'm sticking a tub spout off to the side so that I can sit at either end of the tub without a spout in my back. Some things are "convention" with no good reason...